# Filter input values in Shader Editor any texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders

[image: Trying many things]I am using a musgrave texture and I wanted to apply a low pass filter on fac output, and use it as a displacement in the displacement input of the Material output. I tried the math section but (EDIT)I did not get. Kindly help.

Edit: I added two Diffuse BSDF's with slightly different colors and wanted to filter the musgrave texture to have only low passed values which go into displacement node and then to displacement input of the material,they also go into fac input of mix shader.

Comment: Hi. Do you mean blurring by "low pass filter"? :D

Comment: 1. Not BI, it's Cycles (your tag) -
2. Show us the math for the low pass filter. It's not built-in so you need to reconstruct it.

Comment: I did not say I did it... but rather in the input section, I was searching for how to implement a low pass filter,or even a high pass to have short spikes in the surface...  experimentation leads to increased understanding.